# Issue with ADT plugin in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am new to android and I am setting up eclipse with ADT plugin for android application development. Yesterday (10/18/2011) I downloaded and installed Android SDK Tools(revision 13), Android SDK platform tools(revision 7) and several SDK platforms (2.3.3, 3.0 etc) using the 'Android SDK and AVD manager' without any issues.

But today(10/19/2011) when I go the 'available packages' in the 'Android SDK and AVD manager' I can only see Android SDK Tools(revision 14) and Android SDK platform tools(revision 8) both which were not there yesterday. Worst part is I cannot see any other platforms, documentation, samples etc which I could see under available packages yesterday.

Does anyone knows how I can get the other platforms, documentation, samples..?

Comment: I think you already downloaded it. Have you checked your sdk folder. Android revision 14 is Android 4.0 ICS. It just came today.

Comment: No. I didn't download all of it which was available yesterday. As the description indicates I downloaded only few packages and I was planning to download the rest today. But as indicated I cannot see the rest of the packages now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours of researching I found the cause for this. With the release of Android 4.0, Google has also released a new version of the ADT plugin (i.e. V14.0.0). This version of the ADT plugin has several major changes (at least from UI level) which includes the separation of 'SDK Manager' and 'AVD Manager' as two separate components.

And it seems that Google has also changed the SDK package download process which was previously based on the infamous 'repository.xml' file. This maybe to stop downloading the SDK packages directly from the repository as suggested in several online blogs. And this was the same issue why my older version of the ADT plugin couldn't show the additional packages to be downloaded. In more simple words, Google has removed all the links to these additional packages from the 'repository.xml' file.

With the updated ADT plugin now I can see the other additional packages

Answer (score 0):

You can find the stuff you already installed under "Installed Packages". "Available Packages" is only for new stuff.

Comment: I know that.. But what I need to do is install "NEW" packages that I have not installed yet and the problem is that the "NEW" packages which I could see yesterday is not appearing today..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Also, I cannot install any other plugin (pydev etc) on eclipse juno 4.2

After making so much of search, I understood that we need to have WST server adapters installed as well.

http://time-loop.tumblr.com/post/360049815/installing-android-eclipse-plugin , this link helped me. After installing WST , ADT plugin installation starts working as magic.