# Re-installation of Android SDK r13 cannot see available APIs

Tags: android

I have attempted to update my Android SDK to r14, which broke my code. In an effort to recover my old revision, I've uninstalled the entire SDK, and ran the r13 installer again.

The SDK Manager installs without error. However, the only packages available in the Android Repository are the next revision of the SDK tools (r14) and r8 of the platform-tools. I can't download/install any version of the Android APIs, since none seem to exist.

I should note that if I choose to upgrade to SDK r14 from this state, I can then see the full history of Android/Google APIs available to the manager.

Has anyone else attempted to re-install the Android SDK from old revisions and run into this problem? If so, how have you retrieved and installed the APIs?

- I am running Windows 7, 64-bit

Comment: r14 didn't brake your code, did you try to clean your projects?

Comment: I did not try to clean my projects. Now, however, I am less interested in trying to make my project work with r14 and moreso in trying to get r13 operational again.

Comment: Makes no sence, you'll have to upgrade sooner or later. Don't do an error and stick with it just because you made another one earlier :)

Comment: My code, working or not, is not why I have asked this question. I have asked _specifically_ if anyone has seen a particular behavior when they attempt to re-install their SDK at an old revision. I only mention my code breaking as a way to introduce the question.

Comment: Then wait for someone instead of solving your issue now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the release of ICS (SDK v14), Android has also changed the structure of their SDK archive. Older versions of the SDK tools, specifically older versions of the SDKManager, cannot see the SDK archives because the repository URL is different.

The new Android API archive repository (as of this writing) is located [here](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml).

The new Google API archive is located [here](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml).

You can browse to each URL and download the APIs manually by replacing the xml file names at the end of the URL with the URL file for each API listed.

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816795/issue-with-adt-plugin-in-eclipse).